# Ubuntu 22.10 LTS or not?

Tags: lts, support

[image]

I was under the impression 22.10 was a LTS version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not, did you read any release notes

https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/10/20/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-released/

says rather clearly

> Maintenance updates will be provided for 9 months for all flavours
> releasing with 22.10.

Which is why *end of life* warnings came out awhile ago

https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/14/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-20-2023/

> Ubuntu announced its 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu) release almost 9 months ago,
> on October 20, 2022, and its support period is now nearing its end.
> Ubuntu 22.10 will reach end of life on July 20, 2023.

and very soon, the final EOL notices will be out.

LTS releases are the *first* release in an *even* year, ie. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS was the 2022-April LTS release.

Comment: FYI:   A *full development* cycle for a LTS is two years, it started the week following the release of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and is run in 4 six month mini-cycles; with the results of the first three of those being available as non-LTS release.. ie. 22.10 was the first view of what's being created for 24.04, 23.04 the second, 23.10 will be the last view & closest to the final 24.04 product released in 2024-April.

Comment: Also I just looked at https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release and 22.10 no longer appears as *supported* for installed systems when they check now....   ML post is the final step of the EOL process, so *kinetic* EOL is ~here now.

Comment: Another FYI:  Some of us can *accidentally*  type an LTS when writing a comment on sites such as this in error (*when its not an LTS; esp. on the .04 releases like 23.04*), but I can't imagine that being done an anything official, as all official docs are checked by at least one other person in a team; and even if something did slip thru; it'd be corrected asap or just removed.  My advice would be stick to official release announcements if you want clear facts (*not random bloggers on the internet you don't know*)

Comment: The EOL notice was posted here https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/07/27/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-end-of-life-reached-on-july-20-2023/ , with the details being copied from the ML notice; which is one of the *last* steps on the closure of a release (ie. after all queues of upgraded packages etc completed or were dropped; this notice can get *delayed* so upgrades in queues prior to EOL complete)

Answer (score 1):

As you see here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases the last LTS version before 23.04 had been Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.